# Read an array in helm template from value file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set and read array value like described below , parsing of yaml template file to json is failing , please suggest resolution.

template file :

```
spec:
    arguments: {{ toYaml .Values.sparkapplication.spec.arguments | indent 6 }}
```

values file :

```
sparkapplication :
   spec:
      arguments:
         - val: "/spark_app_prop/config.properties"
         - val: "/spark_app_prop/log4j.properties"
```

expected parsed result in template file should be :

```
spec:
   arguments: [ "/tmp/spark-streaming-poc-app-1.0.0.1/infa_conf/config.properties", "/tmp/spark-streaming-poc-app-1.0.0.1/infa_conf/log4j.properties" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

values.yaml

```yaml
sparkapplication :
  spec:
    arguments:
      - val: "/spark_app_prop/config.properties"
      - val: "/spark_app_prop/log4j.properties"
```

template/cm.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  {{- $list := list }}
  {{- range .Values.sparkapplication.spec.arguments }}
  {{- $list = append $list .val }}
  {{- end }}
  arguments: {{ toJson $list }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  arguments: ["/spark_app_prop/config.properties","/spark_app_prop/log4j.properties"]
```